# Protractor Tests passing without performing the operation on WebPage

Tags: protractor, webdriver

I want my Protractor test to open https://www.jetblue.com/ and click on Round Trip. Below is the piece of code I have written for the same :

```
describe('This test suite will validate booking related features', function(){

    beforeAll(function(){
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 100000;

    })

    beforeEach(function(){
        browser.get('https://www.jetblue.com/');
        browser.getTitle().then(function(text){
            console.log("Title of the page is : " +text);
        });
    });

    it('Customer can search for Flights for One Way Trip', function(){

        var AllElements = element.all(by.xpath("//label[text()=' One-way ']/parent::jb-radio"));

        AllElements.each(function(ele){
            ele.click();
            browser.sleep(10000);
        });

    });

});
```

The test is successfully passing without selecting the radio button. I used the same locators using Selenium-Java and test is actually performing the operation and passing. Makes me think which is actually better as Selenium-Java is equally effective on Angular applications as well.

Comment: which version of protractor do you use?

Comment: This test is always going to pass no matter what happens. You don't have any assertions in the test block. That's how jasmine works, no assertions means green, always. If you want to see it fail you need to add an `expect` statement.

Comment: tehbeardedone - That is not what my understanding is. I have written code previously as well for another web application where the code was just clicking an element or entering some text after which it showed green. Without performing an operation tests should not pass in any framework.

Comment: Sergey Pleshakov - 5.4.2 is the version I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Roundtrip' radio button appears to be this element 
`<div _ngcontent-c47="" class="marker ba b--transparent bg-core-blue t-vfast"></div>`

So I would try to use this locator:
`element(by.css('.marker.ba.b--transparent.bg-core-blue.t-vfast'));`

Comment: Hey Joaquin, thanks for the response. Replaced the it block code with this : element(by.css('.marker.ba.b--transparent.bg-core-blue.t-vfast')).click();  Still facing the same issue.